# How in envoy.blade write such string?

Tags: environment-variables, laravel-blade, gitlab-ci, laravel-envoy

In GitLab CI i have two variables: USER AND HOST.

In envoy.plade I want to get this:

```
@servers(['web' => 'user@host'])
```

I write like this:

```
@servers(['web' => '{{ getenv('USER') }}@{{ getenv('HOST') }}'])
```

But get error, how write it?

Answer (score 2):

Utilize the Composer autoloader and add then add an environment variable like `$DEPLOY_SERVER=user@host` to your `.env` file.

```
@include('vendor/autoload.php')

@setup
    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__, '.env'))->load();
    $ssh = getenv('DEPLOY_SERVER');
@endsetup

@servers(['web' => $ssh])

@story('deploy')
    composer
@endstory

@task('composer')
    echo "Deployment complete, you connected as: {{ $ssh }}";
@endtask
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
   //all below variables are coming from arguments passes with envoy run command
   $name = isset($name) ? $name : null; //web
   $task = isset($task) ? $task : null; //eg list
   $command = isset($command) ? $command : null; //ls (command to run)
   $ip = isset($ip) ? $ip : null; //suppose host is 127.0.0.1
   $user = isset($user) ? $user : null;    
?>

 //Server Connection settings
 {{ $__container->servers([$name => [str_replace('"', '', trim($ip)]])) }}

//Task Details and add the command to run
{{ $__container->startTask($task) }}
    {{$command}}
{{ $__container->endTask() }}

//Open console and in project directory where envoy installed
//envoy command will be like this    
envoy run list --task=list --name=web  --command=ls --ip=127.0.0.1 --user=user
```